# Where is the OID and ASN.1 specified for AES_CMAC?

Tags: aes, cmac, cms

I have a requirement to implement AES_CMAC as the authentication algorithm in a CMS library.  I just can't seem to find the OID and the ASN.1 definition for it.

I expected to see the OID under {joint-iso-itu-t(2) country(16) us(840) organization(1) gov(101) csor(3) nistAlgorithm(4) aes(1)} since it appears to be a NIST Standard ( 800-38B )

Any help out there?  Thanks

Comment: If there was an OID, I'd expect it to be at http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/crypto_apps_infra/csor/algorithms.html#objects, but it seems CMAC is missing.

Comment: The issue may be that CMS authenticated data is probably not used that much. Would it be an option to specify CCM instead? It uses CBC-MAC underneath, but it is secure and probably more widely supported.

Comment: Note: I've searched both the Bouncy Castle libs as well as the [OID repository](http://www.oid-info.com/basic-search.htm) to no avail.

Comment: owlstead - No, CCM is not an option.  It is not possible to stream parse an authenticated-enveloped-data type with that authentication mode.